# silverlight telerik radmap windows 8 touch theme

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, telerik

using silverlight5 telerik radmap with windows 8 touch theme

the zoom and map mode controls do not display properly in "windows8touch" theme

basically exhibiting white text on a white backgroud - options are there but not visible

very simple app see xaml below

-telerik:RadMap  Name="map1"  Grid.Column="0"  ScaleVisibility="Collapsed" CommandBarVisibility="Visible"  NavigationVisibility="Collapsed" Grid.RowSpan="2" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Touch">

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was able to reproduce the issue you wrote us about. Our developers are notified and will further inspect what causes it.
Meanwhile you may use our Implict Styles mechanism to workaround this. Instead of adding the StyleManager.ApplicationTheme setting, you can add the corresponding NoXAML binaries from your local controls installation path. Then merge the needed resource dictionaries for the Windows8Touch theme in App.xaml and voilà.
You may find more about this approach in our Implicit Styles help topic and more specifically in "Applying theme globally in your application" section.

We are sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.
Regards,
Evgenia 
Telerik 
Explore the entire Telerik portfolio by downloading Telerik DevCraft Ultimate.

From: paul
Date: 6/19/2013 8:46:58 AM

i have found the problem

if i remove the line below from the app.xaml.cs it works fine!!!

so it looks ike a bug?
Telerik.Windows.Controls.StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.Windows8TouchTheme();